# maven not able to resolve saxon-8.9.0.4-osgi

Tags: maven, artifactory

I'm building a clients project using maven and artifactory. The following happens when I build it. I can't resolve it using maven on it's own, or when I point it to artifactory using `<mirrorOf>*` in .m2/settings.xml

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project reverseMapping: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.bskyb:reverseMapping:mule:14.6.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact net.sf.saxon:saxon:jar:8.9.0.4-osgi in repo (http://my.artifactory:8081/artifactory/repo) -> [Help 1]

I can see an artifact that appears to be the correct one, here:
http://central.maven.org/maven/mule/dependencies/maven2/net/sf/saxon/saxon/8.9.0.4-osgi/

I can download it with the following command

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get \ 
  -DrepoUrl=http://central.maven.org/maven/mule/dependencies/maven2 \
  -Dartifact=net.sf.saxon:saxon:8.9.0.4-osgi
```

This suggests I need to add a repo to artifactory using the repoUrl in the command above

Is this correct?

What is the correct way to implement this so artifactory can resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Mule dependencies are, apparently not in Maven Central, but in their own repository, located, in a very confusing way, under http://central.maven.org but not in it.

Mule's repository root URL is http://central.maven.org/maven/mule/dependencies/maven2.

You need to add it a new remote repository to Artifactory. The user guide has [the instructions](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories) on how to do it.

You're more than welcome to read all the [Repositories chapter](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories), Artifactory will make more sense to you after grasping some basic concepts (for example why using `repo` repository and `mirrorOf` setting are discouraged).

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why maven cannot, or should not as seems the case, resolve the artifact in question from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 . I realise this is due to a lack of understanding on my part on how precisely the maven repo is organised. I would grateful for an explanation of why we have to add this repo separately.

Comment: Please can we avoid discussing on this thread where repos are declared.

Comment: Thanks. Is it documented anywhere that one can use this repo to resolve mule dependencies? I seem to have arrived at this repo by trial and error more or less.

Comment: Probably somewhere in Mule's docs? I just took the link you provided and showed you how to configure it (btw, if it worked for you, accepting the answer will be appreciated).